# Crash: tid:com.facebook.react.WebSocketModuleQueue RCTSRWebSocket.m SocketRocket: In debug mode. Allowing connection to any root cert

Tags: android, ios, react-native

React-Native App crash after running 30 mins. I have checked there is no memory issue. What the scanerio was. My app was running in the ios Simulator. I didn't stop that. I have created the new instance of Terminal window & Went to android directory then just clean the Gradlew with "./gradlew clean" command, After that i tried to make the android release build with "./gradlew assembleRelease" command.

Is this not acceptable to make android build while running iOS build ?

Comment: Probably just an issue with the packager